# How to add each item in list next to another item in another list and repeating it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi there I've just started learning Python and spent the whole day trying to figure out how to do that

since it is really hard to explain what I'm trying to achieve I will explain it in the following example:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry']

num = [2, 3, 4]
```

## output

```
apple 1
apple 2

banana 1
banana 2
banana 3

strawberry 1
strawberry 2
strawberry 3
strawberry 4
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `num`?

Comment: @Samwise. It's the number of repetitions

Comment: It's fun to learn a new language. But to learn, you really need to put in some effort. Please show what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: That what i did but didn't manage to repeat them                                                  
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry']

num = [2, 3, 4]


zipped = zip(fruits, num)


for (a, b) in zipped:
    print(a, b)

Answer (score 2):

```
for rep, fruit in zip(num, fruits):
    for i in range(rep):
        print('{} {}'.format(fruit, i+1))


apple 1
apple 2
banana 1
banana 2
banana 3
strawberry 1
strawberry 2
strawberry 3
strawberry 4
```

Comment: Awesome man thanks so much, I was playing with zip and I managed to merge them together as i want but didn't know how to repeat them

Comment: Since the quantity is a list coming from external as a data, I got an error  'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
tried  int()  but got this error int() argument must be a string however i managed to solve that with for loop just wondering if there is a better way to do it or if this is okay and thank you again!

def return_num():
    num = []
    for item in quantity:
        num.append(int(item))
    return num

num = return_num()
    

for rep, fruits in zip(num, fruits):
    for i in range(rep):
        print('{} {}'.format(fruits, i+1))

Answer (score 0):

You could write a list comp and enumerate the number of occurances.

```
fruit_prod = [
    (fruit, idx)
    for number, fruits in zip(num, fruits)
    for idx, fruit in enumerate([fruits] * number, 1)
]
```

---

```
[('apple', 1),
 ('apple', 2),
 ('banana', 1),
 ('banana', 2),
 ('banana', 3),
 ('strawberry', 1),
 ('strawberry', 2),
 ('strawberry', 3),
 ('strawberry', 4)]
```

---

```
for fruit,number in fruit_prod:
    print(fruit,number)

apple 1
apple 2
banana 1
banana 2
banana 3
strawberry 1
strawberry 2
strawberry 3
strawberry 4
```